# Given two list of numbers create a new list and it should contain only odd numbers from the first list # and even numbers from the second list

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

learning python.. trying to do.. But not knowing how to fix it..

```
def oddeven(n,List2):
    Result=[]
    N=int(input('Enter the no. of numbers: '))

    for i in range(0,N):
        n = int(input('The even number is: '))
        if (n % 2 == 0):
            Result.append(n)
            return result
    # print('List1', Result)

    for j in range(0,N):
        List2 = int(input('The odd number is: '))
        if (List2 % 2 != 0):
            Result.append(List2)
            return result
    # print('List2', Result)
    #     return Result

oddeven(n,List2)
```

Error message:
   oddeven(n,List2)
NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: Where are input parameter's ``n`` & ``List2`` for function oddeven defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly describes the problem: you haven't defined `n`. You probably supposed to read it from input, but but forgot to implement that. The `List2` is not defined as well.

Actually you even don't use any of these variables, so you may remove them from parameters and arguments.

One more concern: why are you assuming that both lists have the same lengths? You probably need to make your solution more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be like your code, but I do have a suggestion for an alternative way to accomplish the same thing:

```
l1 = [2,5,8,12,4,6,87,32,65]
l2 = [1,6,3,90,4,5,32,4]
l3 = [n for n in l1 if n%2]+[n for n in l2 if not n%2]
print(l3)
```

Output:

```
[5, 87, 65, 6, 90, 4, 32, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid loops altogether with numpy.array().

```
from numpy import array
a=array([1,2,3,4,5,6]) # evens from here
b=array([7,8,9,10,11,12]) # odds from here

c = [*a[a%2 == 0], *b[b%2 != 0]]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue and my code is as follows:

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,121]
l2=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
l3=[]

for i in range(len(l1)):
   if l1[i]%2!=0:
    l3.append(l1[i])
print(l3) 
for i in range(len(l2)):
   if l2[i]%2==0:
     l3.append(l2[i])
print(l3)
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The problem was clearly resolved, a long time ago. In that case, please explain how your answer complements what was already posted.